# Projection map from projective space is not well defined?

Tags: projective-space, projection

Let $f: \mathbb{P^2} \to \mathbb{P^1}$ send $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,z)$. My book is telling me that this map is not well defined at $(0,0,1)$. How is this the case? Here $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$ are the projective spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, that is $\mathbb{P^n}$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} - 0$ over $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: It is well-defined at $(0,0,1)$. It is not well-defined at $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: Why is that? Shouldn't it just be $(0,0)$?

Comment: Is $(0,0)$ a point on the projective line?

Comment: oh, ez, thanks.